# Facebook like box problems using IFrame

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I have a problem with the Facebook [like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) box, from the Facebook developer section. The problem is, whenever I open up my web page, I just get this error message:

> Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or folder wasn't found.

Should I make a file on my own or what?

I'm using the iframe option in HTML programming:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebo
ok.com%2FTriplex.Mobildiskotek&amp;width=800&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=dark&
amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=false" scrolling=
"no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:800px; height:395
px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: please show some code, how can we know whats wrong without it?

Comment: sorry, i'll fix it right away

Comment: is your like button out of date? maybe you need to regenerate it?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, since I just made it today

Comment: trying the code you posted, i get the following message: 'Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.'

Comment: I have now tried to put in the link directly from the facebook page, but i only get the same error message, the page is the following http://www.facebook.com/Triplex.Mobildiskotek

Comment: I have solved it myself, just had to put         https://     in front of the URL

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTriplex.Mobildiskotek&amp;width=800&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;appId=219650941461322" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:800px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

You can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/nbeQH/.

The first is your code, the second is mine. So you could see yours gives an error, while the other doesn't.

Comment: i can see it's working on the link you provided, but whenever i copy paste it to dreamweaver, all i get, is the same error as earlier :/

Comment: maybe dreamweaver messes it up? try adding it with a simple text editor like notepad.

Comment: this is in FF, RockMelt and Chrome. whereas in safari, it doesn't show anything else than the two wrappers and the dropdown menu i made

Comment: that is a totaly diffrent problem :)

Comment: i know, it was also just an FYI ;) but i have tried putting it in a textedit dokument, with the .html ending, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You need to add http: to the beginning of the code and you're all set.

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins...
```